# Random tridiagonal matrix from matlab to python

Tags: python, matlab, numpy

I want to try  to implement the following code from Matlab to Python (I am not familiar with Python in general, but I try to translate it from Matlab using basics)

```
% n is random integer from 1 to 10
% first set the random seed (because we want our results to be reproducible;
% the seed sets a starting point in the sequence of random numbers the program
rng(n)
 
% Generate random columns
a = rand(n, 1);
b = rand(n, 1);
c = rand(n, 1);

% Convert to a matrix
A = zeros(n);
for i = 1:n
    if i ~= n
        A(i + 1, i) = a(i + 1);
        A(i, i + 1) = c(i);
    end
    A(i, i) = b(i);
end
```

This is my attempt in Python:

```
import numpy as np
## n is random  integer  from 1 to 10
np.random.seed(n)

### generate random columns: 
a = np.random.rand(n)
b = np.random.rand(n)
c = np.random.rand(n)

A = np.zeros((n, n)) ## create zero n-by-n  matrix
for i in range(0, n):
    if  (i != n):
         A[i + 1, i] = a[i + 1]
         A[i, i + 1] = c[i]
    A[i, i] = b[i]
```

I run into an error on the line `A[i + 1, i] = a[i]`. Is  there any structure in Python that I am missing out here?

Comment: When i=n-1, i+1 will be too large for your nxn matrix, which in python is indexed 0..n-1

Comment: To make an MCVE, set `n` to a specific value.

Comment: The correct check is `(i!=n-1)` because of zero-based indexing

Answer (score 2):

Short answer is that `for i = 1:n` iterates `[1, n]`, inclusive on both bounds, while `for i in range(n):` iterates `[0, n)`, exclusive on the right bound. Therefore, the check `if i ~= n` correctly tests if you are at the right edge, while `if  (i!=n):` does not. Replace it with

```
if  i != n - 1:
```

The long answer is that you don't need any of that code in either language, since both MATLAB and numpy are intended to be used with vectorized operations. In MATLAB, you can write

```
A = diag(a(2:end), -1) + diag(b, 0) + diag(c(1:end-1), +1)
```

In numpy, it's very similar:

```
A = np.diag(a[1:], -1) + np.diag(b, 0) + np.diag(c[:-1], +1)
```

There are other tricks you can use, especially if you just want random numbers in the matrix:

```
A = np.random.rand(n, n)
A[np.tril_indices(n, -2)] = A[np.triu_indices(n, 2)] = 0
```

You can use other index-based approaches:

```
i, j = np.diag_indices(n)
i = np.concatenate((i[:-1], i, i[1:]))
j = np.concatenate((j[1:], j, j[:-1]))
A = np.zeros((n, n))
A[i, j] = np.random.rand(3 * n - 2)
```

Answer (score 2):

As the above comments clearly points out the indexing error, here is a numpy way of doing it based on [np.diag](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.diag.html):

```
import numpy as np

# for reproducibility
np.random.seed(42)

# n is random  integer  from 1 to 10
n = np.random.randint(low=1, high=10)

# first diagonal below main diag: k = -1
a = np.random.rand(n-1)
# main diag: k = 0
b = np.random.rand(n) 
# first diagonal above main diag: k = 1
c = np.random.rand(n-1)

# sum all 2-d arrays in order to obtain A
A = np.diag(a, k=-1) + np.diag(b, k=0) + np.diag(c, k=1)
```